Title: Initialization Issue with flutter_stripe Due to Android Theme Settings
I am encountering an issue while initializing the flutter_stripe plugin in my Flutter application. The error suggests that my application's theme is not using Theme.AppCompat or Theme.MaterialComponents, which are required by the plugin. Here is the specific error message:
vbnet
Copy code
PlatformException (flutter_stripe initialization failed, The plugin failed to initialize:
Your theme isn't set to use Theme.AppCompat or Theme.MaterialComponents.
Please make sure you follow all the steps detailed inside the README: [link]
If you continue to have trouble, follow this discussion to get some support [link])

I have checked my styles.xml file and it appears to be correct, using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar as its parent. Additionally, I have ensured that the theme is applied in my AndroidManifest.xml.
Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong or if there are any additional steps I might have missed in properly setting up the theme for flutter_stripe?
Thank you for your assistance!
I am developing a Flutter application with Stripe integration and encountered the following error:
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, lateinit property stripeSdk has not been initialized, null, kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property stripeSdk has not been initialized
    at com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin.getStripeSdk(StripeAndroidPlugin.kt:34)
    at com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1.invoke(StripeAndroidPlugin.kt:59)
    at com....

On IOS everything was okay; the problem occured on android.
The error suggests that the stripeSdk property has not been initialized before its use. I have ensured that the SDK should be initialized in the onAttachedToEngine method, but it seems like the SDK is still uninitialized when it's accessed. So I had this line inside my main :
await.Sripe.instance.applyStteings(),

Looking at the flutter_stripe example app (https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart), it looks like they set  Stripe.publishableKey,   Stripe.merchantIdentifier, and  Stripe.urlScheme before calling await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
Can you confirm you have set all of those parameters correctly?

Any update to this issue? I'm facing the same.
